# unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffff975ef740ad

Tags: ubuntu, radeon

My PC crash sometimes. I can see the screen, and things seems to be running but the display is frozen. Most of the time it's correct but sometimes in crash when I do nothing particularly. It can happens 3 or 4 times in row.

The last time, I had this error in the syslog :

```
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.430097] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffff975ef740ad
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.430149] IP: ttm_bo_del_from_lru+0x41/0xa0 [ttm]
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.430174] PGD 1bc60c067 
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.430175] PUD 0 
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.430190] 
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.430210] Oops: 0002 [#1] SMP
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.430227] Modules linked in: xt_nat xt_tcpudp veth authenc echainiv esp4 xfrm4_mode_tunnel ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 xt_addrtype iptable_filter xt_conntrack nf_nat nf_conntrack libcrc32c br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) deflate twofish_generic twofish_avx_x86_64 twofish_x86_64_3way twofish_x86_64 twofish_common camellia_generic camellia_aesni_avx_x86_64 camellia_x86_64 serpent_avx_x86_64 serpent_sse2_x86_64 serpent_generic lrw blowfish_generic blowfish_x86_64 blowfish_common cast5_avx_x86_64 cast5_generic cast_common ablk_helper des_generic cmac xcbc rmd160 af_key xfrm_algo binfmt_misc intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.430579]  coretemp kvm_intel kvm snd_usb_audio irqbypass snd_usbmidi_lib crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul uvcvideo ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 joydev videobuf2_core videodev media input_leds aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd intel_cstate snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl_perf snd_hda_codec_via snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_rawmidi snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd mei_me lpc_ich soundcore mei shpchp ie31200_edac tpm_infineon edac_core mac_hid serio_raw parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 amdgpu hid_generic amdkfd amd_iommu_v2 radeon psmouse i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect pata_acpi sysimgblt fb_sys_fops
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.430930]  drm atl1c usbhid hid fjes video
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.430956] CPU: 2 PID: 3438 Comm: radeon_cs:0 Tainted: G           OE   4.10.0-37-generic #41-Ubuntu
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431000] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. To be filled by O.E.M./Z77-D3H, BIOS F13 05/11/2012
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431047] task: ffff975efad48000 task.stack: ffffb94688bc8000
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431079] RIP: 0010:ttm_bo_del_from_lru+0x41/0xa0 [ttm]
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431106] RSP: 0018:ffffb94688bcb778 EFLAGS: 00010287
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431132] RAX: ffff975f46bd2538 RBX: ffff975f46bd2468 RCX: ffffff975ef740a5
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431166] RDX: ffff975dc25c7938 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff975f46bd2468
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431200] RBP: ffffb94688bcb780 R08: ffff975d74cf8e88 R09: ffff975d74cfb800
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431234] R10: ffff975d74cf8800 R11: ffff975f47c6f9c0 R12: ffff975d74cfbe88
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431268] R13: ffff975f46bd2468 R14: ffff975f43063d38 R15: ffffb94688bcbb48
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431302] FS:  00007f8040c37700(0000) GS:ffff975f5ed00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431341] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431369] CR2: ffffff975ef740ad CR3: 00000003bf083000 CR4: 00000000001406e0
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431403] Call Trace:
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431422]  ttm_eu_reserve_buffers+0x18b/0x380 [ttm]
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431470]  radeon_bo_list_validate+0x91/0x210 [radeon]
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431499]  ? __kmalloc+0x162/0x1e0
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431537]  radeon_cs_parser_relocs+0x391/0x460 [radeon]
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431584]  radeon_cs_ioctl+0xf5/0x840 [radeon]
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431621]  drm_ioctl+0x21b/0x4c0 [drm]
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431659]  ? radeon_cs_parser_init+0x30/0x30 [radeon]
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431699]  radeon_drm_ioctl+0x4f/0x90 [radeon]
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431724]  do_vfs_ioctl+0xa3/0x610
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431743]  ? SyS_futex+0x85/0x180
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431762]  SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431781]  entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x1e/0xad
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431804] RIP: 0033:0x7f805d73d587
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431822] RSP: 002b:00007f8040c36db8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431859] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055beabf85fc0 RCX: 00007f805d73d587
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431893] RDX: 000055beab9b3d90 RSI: 00000000c0206466 RDI: 000000000000000d
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431928] RBP: 00007f8040c36d40 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000000000000343d
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431962] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000040086409
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.431996] R13: 000000000000000d R14: 00000000186c0000 R15: 000055beacb92c10
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.432030] Code: 8b 40 70 48 85 c0 74 02 ff d0 48 8b 93 d0 00 00 00 48 8d 83 d0 00 00 00 48 39 d0 74 64 48 8b 8b d0 00 00 00 48 8b 93 d8 00 00 00 <48> 89 51 08 48 89 0a 48 89 83 d0 00 00 00 48 89 83 d8 00 00 00 
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.432148] RIP: ttm_bo_del_from_lru+0x41/0xa0 [ttm] RSP: ffffb94688bcb778
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.432180] CR2: ffffff975ef740ad
Oct 24 05:50:21 oscar kernel: [  814.444514] ---[ end trace d83ec228581c1e27 ]---
```

I did a memtest but I have no errors in my RAM. I saw there is "radeon" in the stack trace so I supposed this can be related to my graphic card.

Here is some info on my system :

```
Linux oscar 4.10.0-37-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 6 20:20:37 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And about my graphic card :

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770/8760 / R7 250X] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] R7770-PMD1GD5
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f7e00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

What can I do?